# C# simplifying generic user control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have implemented a generic user control by doing:

```
public class GenericControl<T> : Control {}
public class CustomerTypeControlParent : GenericControl<CustomerType> {}
public class CustomerTypeControl : CustomerTypeControlParent {}
```

I'm doing the above so that I can place the inherited control (CustomerTypeControl) in the form designer. This is working fine. However I have over 50 such controls, and although most of the code is contained within the generic control itself, it doesn't look like a clean solution.

One problem is that I can't use an interface because, for example, CustomerType exposes Name and Description fields, whilst ProductCategory exposes Number and Description. Other entities expose different fields.

Furthermore, I don't want to use just one control and then having a long switch statement to determine what kind of object I currently have, cast it and get the appropriate fields.

I also use the above method so that I can strongly type.

So is there a cleaner approach to the above?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice is to always have a specific GUI element for each model or entity with the same type of data.
'Name and Description' seems different to 'Number and Description' so you should have two separate GUI controls.
If they actually should use the same GUI element, then I don't see why you can't use an interface like this:

```
public interface ITextAndDescription
{
    string Text;
    string Description;
}
```

You would then implement this for CustomerType and ProductCategory and there you go.